# Java Socket readLine() infinite, ends only if php script times out

Tags: java, php, sockets, loops

I want to send a message with socket to an java server and it should response.

```
InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream());
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
String clientSentence = input.readLine();
System.out.println(clientSentence);
```

This infinite, so I can't send a response to my php socket connection.

PHP:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
$st="testSalt,broadcast";
$length = strlen($st);

socket_write($socket, $st, $length);

$resp = socket_read($socket, 1024);
```

Comment: please define "infinite".  As in, it never continues over to the next line of code?  If so, this is called _blocking_.  `input.readLine()` is blocking while it waits for a line to read.

Comment: I don't know much about PHP, but it looks to me that if you send the contents of `$st` as-is, there won't be any newline character for the Java socket to read, and thus the `readLine()` call will hang until the `Socket` closes.

Comment: Yep.  I was just about to say that @BenLawry, good catch.  user, you need to put a newline character at the end of your string.

Comment: "\n" behind my message did it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminate strings from the PHP socket with a newline character to match the `readLine` statement of the Java server

```
$st = "testSalt,broadcast\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about PHP, but it looks to me that if you send the contents of `$st` as-is, there won't be any newline character for the Java socket to read, and thus the `input.readLine()` call will hang until the `Socket` closes.